# Unable to export Rest API output to CSV via Azure Powershell RunBook

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to export VMs list from Azure Update management using Azure Rest API. Below is my code.
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($SubscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$($resourceGroup)/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/$($automationAccount)/softwareUpdateConfigurations/$($UpdateScheduleName)?api-version=" + $apiversion
$RestMethod = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headerParams -Method Get)
$NonAzComputerList  = ($RestMethod).Properties.updateConfiguration.nonAzureComputerNames
$NonAzComputerList.GetType().FullName
Write-Output $NonAzComputerList
$NonAzComputerList | Export-Csv "VMList.csv" -NoTypeInformation

On Console, I do get the output correctly with VM names, but in CSV file, I get some random numbers instead of VM names.

I tried convertfrom-json as well but it shows error as "convertfrom-json : Invalid JSON primitive".

The GetType shows System.Object[]

In Console, I am getting correct VM names.
OurVM01
OurVM022
OurVM0113
OurVM034

In CSV file, I am getting numbers (equal to number of characters in VM names).
List
07
08
09
08

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. Used out-file instead of export-csv